# How can I load a multiple select after jQuery select change?

Tags: jquery, html, html-select, multiple-select

I have this code:

```
 <select required class="form-control" name="selecao_maquina" id="selecao_maquina">
     <option>opcao1</option>
     <option>opcao2</option>
 </select>
<select multiple name="selecao_modelos[]" required class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
</select>
```

And my jQuery function is that:

```
$("#selecao_maquina").change(function(){
    $('#selecao_modelos[]').html('<option>oi</option');  
})
```

It doesn't work! I need that when I change the first select it loads the second selection in a different way.

How can I do that?

Comment: What kind of "different way"? Could you please include examples of your expected result and the actual result?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your second selector: `$('#selecao_modelos[]')`

You're trying to select an ID, but it is an attribute "name". You can select this attribute using $('[name="selecao_modelos[]"]'), or keep the original selector and set the id of the html element to the same value.